# How many config file requried for two session factory?

Tags: java, hibernate

If I have two session factory , it means I am using two DB schema in my application, so is it required two config file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need one config file. Just add multiple session-factories like this:

```
<session-factory name="firstdatasource">
  <property name="datasource">my/first/datasource</property>
  <mapping resource="..."/>
 ..
</session-factory>

<session-factory>
  <property name="datasource">seconddatasource</property>
  ..
</session-factory>
```